# How to pass Kapt compiler arguments

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Passing `kapt` argument with gradle build script is pretty straight forward

```
kapt {
   arguments {
      arg("codegen.output", "path.to.file")
   }
}
```

Although I read through the documentation of kapt and kotlin, downloaded the source code for the kotlin plugin and kapt plugin and looked inside, I was not successful to find a way to do this programmatically via a gradle plugin.

Is there a way to do it? is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question just after I realized that in `kotlin-gradle-plugin` version `1.4.20` the enhanced `kotlin-gradle-dsl` can be used in plugins development to pass `kapt` arguments in the following fashion

```kotlin
project.extensions.findByType(KaptExtension::class.java)?.let { kapt ->
                    kapt.arguments {
                        arg("sample.argument", "sample value")
                    }
                }
```

Comment: how to find KaptExtension？